# Windows Forms Updating Controls from other threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)
>   [My Timer event crashes because the events are called on a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349305/my-timer-event-crashes-because-the-events-are-called-on-a-different-thread)

I have a timer object that I want to periodically update a UI control which is a label.  However it crashes and says I need to update it on the UI thread.  Can anyone help?

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);          
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
   }
   public void updateUI()
    {

        lblAirTrack.Text = "Tracking: " + itemList.Count + " items";

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5+, use the dispatcher.  Otherwise something like this should work:

```
private delegate void updateUIDelegate();

public void updateUI()
{
    if (lblAirTrack.InvokeRequired)
    {
        lblAirTrack.Invoke(new updateUIDelegate(updateUI));
    }
    else
    {
        lblAirTrack.Text = "Tracking: " + itemList.Count + " items";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, what if updateUI has some parameters to pass.  I've tried working this out but always get IDE errors

Comment: For example, if it took a string, add the string parameter to both updateUIDelegate and updateUI.  Then, when you invoke: lblAirTrack.Invoke(new updateUIDelegate(updateUI), newParameterGoesHere);

Answer (score 2):

For WPF, use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx), for Windows forms, I think [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) should do what you're looking for.

The difference of these two timers to the System.Timers.Timer-class is, that they raise the Tick-event in the UI thread. If you use the System.Timers.Timer, you have to manually route your calls to UI elements to the UI thread. In wpf, use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to do this. Use[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx). In winforms use [Control.BeginInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx)